# Is there a way to allow certain email senders to load Mail content directly?

Tags: mail.app, security

With Monterey's Mail.app, there is now the network protection feature which is great and I want to keep it on. When you open an email, it prevents image loading and has a banner that says "Your network preferences prevent content from loading privately". However, there are a few specific email addresses which I would like to automatically "Load Content Directly" with.

Is there a way to allow specific sender addresses to automatically load? In the app's preferences, I can only see a full on/off checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Source: [If you see 'Unable to load remote content privately' at the top of an email](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212797)

The short answer appears to be no. Because of how the feature works it hides your IP for all mail traffic. There's no setting in there to have certain contacts get loaded directly and at that point it would be up to the sender's servers to determine if the mail will load anonymously or not.